# Restore session in CherryPy by specific id

Tags: session, cherrypy

I am doing a RESTful web service by CherryPy. Since the client is not always a browser and may not be able to store cookie, so I plan to get CherryPy's session id and pass it via HTTP GET/POST as a token. When client send request with this token(session id) to CherryPy it could restore session just like what cookie does and the server side can get authentication or any stateful data.

My question is, how to restore the CherryPy session by specific id?

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import cherrypy.lib


config = {
  'global' : {
    'server.socket_host' : '127.0.0.1',
    'server.socket_port' : 8080,
    'server.thread_pool' : 4
  }
}


class App:

  @cherrypy.expose
  @cherrypy.config(**{'tools.sessions.on': True})
  def counter(self):
    if 'counter' not in cherrypy.session:
      cherrypy.session['counter'] = 0
    cherrypy.session['counter'] += 1

    return 'Counter: {0}<br/>Session key: {1}'.format(
      cherrypy.session['counter'], 
      cherrypy.request.cookie['session_id'].value
    )

  @cherrypy.expose
  def recreate(self, token):
    '''You can try open it from another browser 
    once set the value in /counter
    '''
    cherrypy.request.cookie['session_id'] = token
    cherrypy.lib.sessions.init()
    # now it should be ready
    return 'Counter: {0}'.format(cherrypy.session['counter'])



if __name__ == '__main__':
  cherrypy.quickstart(App(), '/', config)
```

Comment: He mentioned the request is not coming from a browser and cannot use cookies to store the session id.

Comment: Hi saaj, I focus on setting cookie['session_id'] = token and call init(). After test it did not work and cannot retrieve the exist session content back. PS. I'm using curl and HTTP GET to test token.

Comment: @AndrewKloos Your comment isn't relevant because the code is faking request cookie which doesn't relate to client capabilities.

Comment: @Takol It shouldn't make any difference whether you use curl or another browser for the demo. Internal session handling is off at ``/recreate`` and it's triggered manually. The demo code works fine: start the app, open /counter, refresh it a couple of times, copy token, open /recreate?token=TOKEN at another agent. Make sure the demo code works for you, then port the approach to you real code.

Comment: @Takoi I see... well going to recreate + token return error.  KeyError: 'counter'

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by saaj I found a solution that works.  Try this...

```
import cherrypy.lib

config = {
  'global' : {
    'server.socket_host' : '127.0.0.1',
    'server.socket_port' : 8080,
    'server.thread_pool' : 4,
    'tools.sessions.on': True,
    'tools.sessions.storage_type': "file",
    'tools.sessions.storage_path': "adf"
  }
}


class Helloworld:
    @cherrypy.expose
    def make(self, token=''):
        '''You can try open it from another browser 
        once set the value in /counter
        '''

        if(token == ''):
            cherrypy.lib.sessions.init()
            # take this token and put in the url 127.0.0.1:8080/make/ + token
            return cherrypy.session.id
        else:
            #send two requests with the token. 1. to set a session var 
            #  and 2. to retrieve the var from session
            cherrypy.lib.sessions.init(self, id=token)

            print('do something')
            # on the second request check the value after init and it's HI!
            cherrypy.session['something'] = 'HI'            

        return token

if __name__ == '__main__':
  cherrypy.quickstart(Helloworld(), '/', config)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The previous examples didn't work for me (at least for file sessions). Maybe because the current version of cherrypy forbids session init for already initialized sessions. What did work, however, is this:

```
cherrypy.session.id = token
cherrypy.session._load()
```

I understand this is dirty, since the private method is called, but it's the only way I found.